# What is the deterministic hash to EC function used to construct the key image?

Tags: cryptonote, viewkey, cryptography, key-image

Ring signatures alone would allow double spending, so Monero (as a result of following the [CrpytoNote whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf)) has to use a 'key image', which is the same across identical transactions and hence causes attempts at double spending to be rejected.

The key image is formed `I = x*H(P)`, with `I` the key image, `x` the private key, `H` a deterministic hash function, and `P` a ephemeral public key for use in this transaction only.

My question is, in Monero's specific case, what hashing algorithm does `H` represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/2846d0850d6e92d38c44eac9e6a4fca6b1545453/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L255), we can see how it's generated.

```
void crypto_ops::generate_key_image(const public_key &pub, const secret_key &sec, key_image &image) {
    ge_p3 point;
    ge_p2 point2;
    assert(sc_check(&sec) == 0);
    hash_to_ec(pub, point);
    ge_scalarmult(&point2, &sec, &point);
    ge_tobytes(&image, &point2);
  }
```

The `hash_to_ec` function is called to hash `pub` (which is your `P`) into `point`, giving us your `H(P)`. Then, scalar multiplication is performed and result passed into `point2`, which would be your `x*H(P)`. Some transfromation `ge_tobytes` is applied and the result is passed into `image` which is your `I`.

I'm not sure what this `ge_tobytes` transformation does, though. It could be just changing the format of `I` in memory. Implementation specific, I suppose.

The `hash_to_ec` [function](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/2846d0850d6e92d38c44eac9e6a4fca6b1545453/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L245) is presented below.

```
static void hash_to_ec(const public_key &key, ge_p3 &res) {
    hash h;
    ge_p2 point;
    ge_p1p1 point2;
    cn_fast_hash(std::addressof(key), sizeof(public_key), h);
    ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime(&point, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&h));
    ge_mul8(&point2, &point);
    ge_p1p1_to_p3(&res, &point2);
  }
```

We see that the `cn_fast_hash` [function](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/2846d0850d6e92d38c44eac9e6a4fca6b1545453/src/crypto/hash.c#L46) is called, which would be the Keccak hash function.
After getting the hash `h`, it is passed through some functions, which I suspect perform scalar multiplication of `h` with something, but my understanding stops here. This `ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime` might be of interest as Shen Noether did a dedicated [write-up](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/tree/master/whitepaper/ge_fromfe_writeup) on it. Also, [here](http://archive.is/yfINb) we see the importance of using a secure hash function for the key images. Apparently, to do this *something* after the Keccak is quite important.

Shen Noether's [implementation](https://github.com/monero-project/mininero) in Python could provide some insights as well, but I'm not sure if it's up to date.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think `ge_tobytes` means group element to bytes, so it's just typecasting the input from a group element (or more specifically an elliptic curve point) to a byte array. Thanks again :)

Comment: @bekah No problem at all! Fyi, I've bumped into something regarding `ge_fromfe...` which might be of interest as well. Updated the answer.

Comment: See Signature, step 1, Section 3.3 of https://github.com/kurtmagnus/Monero-RCT-report/blob/master/main.pdf
It's essentially private key * Hash_p(public key)
(Hash_p is a hash function that returns an EC point)